# Does "Arcus Cultus Aegeas" mean anything?

Tags: nanoha

on [Fate's Wikia page](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Fate#Powers) it states her

> personal incantation for the set-up of Bardiche is "Arcus Cultus Aegeas" (アルカス・クルタス・エイギアス Arukasu Kurutasu Eigiasu)

Seeing as the phrase is written in Katakana, my understanding on Japanese is that Katakana is generally used for either names of non-native words

also alot of the names in *Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha* are derived from cars such as the [Ferrari Testarossa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrari_Testarossa), [Nissan Presea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissan_Presea), [Nissan Teana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nissan_Teana) or the [Subaru Car Manufacture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subaru), not to mention [Bardiche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/bardiche) is the name of a polearm that was used in medieval and renaissance Europe, especially in Eastern Europe and Russia.

So i am wondering if *"Arcus Cultus Aegeas"* has any other meaning to it, or if it's just some made up aria for Fate to use.

Comment: I don't really have much interest in nanoha, but the three words you're asking for seem to be Latin or Greek. However seeing as either is pretty much non existent in my language list, I'm unable to tell you what they mean. Also I don't wish to apply google translate for obvious reasons. The one word I do recognize from greek myhtology is Aegeas, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aegeus

Comment: Latin. Arcus stands for bow (or arc), cultus is referring to cultist movement and Aegeas can refer to the greek hero or the greek main island itself. interestingly the first 2 words are latin and the second is greek.